# Webstorm: how to exclude javascript from code completion in typescript project

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a project where most of my code is Typescript and it is obviously compiled to Javascript. The problem is that code completion uses both Typescript and Javascript so it usually shows two sources for one class and doesn't show type errors.

[image: TypeScript and JavaScript code completion]

The question is how can I remove a folder with compiled Javascript from being indexed by code completion?

UPD: I'm using upcoming Webstorm 7 EAP

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the folder that contains your compiled javascript and select "**Mark Directory As**" then "**Excluded**".

WebStorm will hide the directory from the project view, stop indexing it for searches and code completion, and not include it in code refactoring tracing. I tend to mark all build output as ignored and ensure that WebStorm is only worrying itself with the source.